# Why won't bokeh figure update with new data?

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I'm creating a bokeh application that pulls data from [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/databases/WIKIP) stock prices and changes the plot based the stock symbol the user inputs. I used an example from this [bokeh tuorial](https://hub.mybinder.org/user/bokeh-bokeh-notebooks-ioxngy9g/notebooks/tutorial/11%20-%20Running%20Bokeh%20Applictions.ipynb) as a model.

Everything is working except the plot won't update when I input a new symbol.

I've tried passing the new data as a dictionary (before I was just passing a DataFrame to `ColumnDataSource()`, but no luck.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput, Select
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.layouts import column, row
from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook
import quandl
```

This is the function to get the data:

```py
def get_data(symbol):
    dictionary = {}
    data = quandl.get('WIKI/' + symbol, collapse = 'annual', returns='numpy')
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    dictionary['date'] = list(df.Date.values)
    dictionary['high'] = list(df.High.values)
    return dictionary
```

And this is a function for the plot:

```py
def modify_doc(doc):
    symbol = 'AAWW'
    source = ColumnDataSource(data = get_data(symbol))

    p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', title='Stock Price', plot_height=350, plot_width=800)
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.5
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'year'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'close'

    r = p.line(source.data['date'], 
               source.data['high'], 
               line_color = 'navy')

    select = Select(title="Color", value="navy", options=COLORS)
    input = TextInput(title="Ticker Symbol", value=symbol)

    def update_symbol(attrname, old, new):
        source.data = get_data(input.value)
    input.on_change('value', update_symbol)

    layout = column(row(input, width=400), row(p))

    doc.add_root(layout)

show(modify_doc)
```

I would think that the plot would update when the new symbol is entered, but it just stays the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are you correctly deploying with the bokeh server?

Comment: I believe so. I'm deploying it within a Jupyter notebook. So `from bokeh.io import show, output_notebook` and then `output_notebook()`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Library names keep getting weirder and weirder. I wonder how they came up with `Quandl` and `bokeh`..?

Comment: A great mystery! 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks like Bokeh server application but you use show() what doesn't look good to me. You are also trying to update the figure by assigning new data to the source but you did not pass your source to the figure object so it won't have any effect. Could you try if this code works for you? (should work for Bokeh v1.0.4)

```
import random
import pandas as pd
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers.function import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import TextInput
from bokeh.layouts import column, row

def make_document(doc):
    symbol = 'AAWW'

    def get_data(symbol):
        dictionary = {}
        data = quandl.get('WIKI/' + symbol, collapse = 'annual', returns = 'numpy')
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        dictionary['date'] = list(df.Date.values)
        dictionary['high'] = list(df.High.values)
        return dictionary

    source = ColumnDataSource(data = get_data(symbol))

    p = figure(x_axis_type = 'datetime', title = 'Stock Price', plot_height = 350, plot_width = 800)
    p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
    p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha = 0.5
    p.xaxis.axis_label = 'year'
    p.yaxis.axis_label = 'close'

    r = p.line(x = 'date',
               y = 'high',
               source = source,
               line_color = 'navy')

    input = TextInput(title = "Ticker Symbol", value = symbol)

    def update_symbol(attrname, old, new):
        source.data = get_data(input.value)

    input.on_change('value', update_symbol)

    layout = column(row(input, width = 400), row(p))
    doc.add_root(layout)

io_loop = IOLoop.current()
server = Server({'/myapp': Application(FunctionHandler(make_document))}, port = 5001, io_loop = io_loop)
server.start()
server.show('/myapp')
io_loop.start()
```

Basically the main change is here:

```
r = p.line(x = 'date',
           y = 'high',
           source = source,
           line_color = 'navy')
```

Comment: Yes, this did work. Thank you! Just out of curiosity, how would you run this from inside a Jupyter notebook?

Comment: No problem. It turns out everything works fine if I just change that the arguments for `p.line()` like you did above. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer I got from Tony, I just had to change one line of code:

```py
r = p.line(x = 'date',
           y = 'high',
           source = source,
           line_color = 'navy')
```